# Can An Unregulated Firm Without Any Solicitors Send Pre Action Protocol Letters?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection, legal-writing, solicitor

As I understand it, in the UK:

(a) The provision of legal advice or assistance in connection with the application of the law or with any form of resolution of legal disputes;

(b) The provision of representation in connection with any matter concerning the application of the law or any form of resolution of legal disputes.

are unreserved legal activities. My understanding is that writing a letter before action on behalf of one of a person would fall under (b) above and thus no formal qualifications or regulation are required. Is that assumption correct?

For the avoidance of all doubt, as a hypothetical scenario, if a company was to write and send a letter before action on their own letterhead stating that we are representing "Alice" and explaining why Alice intends to take legal action would this be legal without being a registered solicitor?

Thanks

Comment: You're writing a legal advice chatbot and you're asking for legal advice from randos on the web?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! @BlueDogRanch. We are providing people with access to legal resources. This doesn't require specialist knowledge and if you think about it, is a good thing because it makes the law more accessible.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are doing; this site is not for specific legal advice. I really hope for your own sake that you have talked to a lawyer.

Comment: Do I understand that you are looking for a delineation of the border between what is legal advice and what is not legal advise in the area of dispute resolution?

Comment: I don't see the reason for the downvotes. It is a legitimate question (as a non-UK practitioner I don't know the answer).

Comment: Asking a clearly off-topic question is a good reason for downvotes. *"We've got a company that might do something illegal, but we think it's okay. Can you give us legal advice about whether we can give legal advice?"* And then the plan is to themselves give legal advice - which they don't apparently know enough to do properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't legally represent someone without being authorised or exempt under sections [18](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/29/section/18) and [19](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/29/section/19) of the Legal Services Act 2007:

This is because both the "right of audience" and the "conduct of litigation" is a reserved legal activity under [section 12](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/29/section/12) of the Act:

> (1) In this Act “reserved legal activity” means—
>
> (a) the exercise of a right of audience;
>
> (b) the conduct of litigation;
>
> (c) reserved instrument activities;
>
> (d) probate activities;
>
> (e) notarial activities;
>
> (f) the administration of oaths.

It is an offence under [section 14](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/29/section/14) of the Act to carry out any of the above, as well as being an offence under [section 17](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/29/section/17) to pretend to be entitled. Furthermore, anyone professing to be entitled to conduct litigation when not so entitled would also be in contempt of court.

However, you may provide the following services without qualification:

> (i) the provision of legal advice or assistance in connection with the application of the law or with any form of resolution of legal disputes;
>
> (ii) the provision of representation in connection with any matter concerning the application of the law or any form of resolution of legal disputes.

as these are not reserved legal activities and are not regulated by the Act. So, you could provide a template letter for the person to write and send off their own letter before action, but you wouldn't be allowed to send it on their behalf.

This is because, arguably, letters before action are part of the expected pre-action protocol under the Civil Procedure Rules and therefore constitute part of the conduct of litigation as they are issued as an ancillary function and indeed clause c of [Schedule 2, part 4 of the Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2007/29/schedule/2/crossheading/conduct-of-litigation) covers such ancillary functions:

> The “conduct of litigation” means—
>
> (a) the issuing of proceedings before any court in England and Wales,
>
> (b) the commencement, prosecution and defence of such proceedings, and
>
> (c) the performance of any ancillary functions in relation to such proceedings (such as entering appearances to actions).

Therefore, you cannot send the letter on behalf of Alice and you cannot represent to be a solicitor, barrister, lawyer, etc. at any point on your website or in your communications with anybody.